# Getting Error c.outlet is not a function in solidjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, webview

Getting this error in solidjs. It is working fine when opening in web, but after deploying it and opening the url in webview (from ReactNative code), i am getting this error in web console, due to which it is not rendering. Not sure this error is exactly related to routes or anything else.

Also this error comes only on opening the web url in webview, in web it works fine

```
TypeError: c.outlet is not a function
at get children [as children] (index.21a14473.js:1:27599)
at Object.fn (index.21a14473.js:1:7536)
at Kn (index.21a14473.js:1:5104)
at de (index.21a14473.js:1:5047)
at T (index.21a14473.js:1:1728)
at Xt (index.21a14473.js:1:4096)
at index.21a14473.js:1:7527
at k (index.21a14473.js:1:3312)
at Object.fn (index.21a14473.js:1:7496)
at Kn (index.21a14473.js:1:5104)
```

I am using  `"solid-app-router": "^0.3.2", "solid-js": "^1.3.15"`. I am registering routes as

Routes.jsx

```
import { Router, useRoutes } from 'solid-app-router';
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: lazy(() => import('./Home')),
},
{
    path: '/about',
    component: lazy(() => import('./about')),
}
]
const App = () =>{
const Routes = useRoutes(routes)
 return (
    <Router>
       <Routes/>
    </Router>
 )
}
```

Index.js

```
import { render } from 'solid-js/web'
import Routes from './Routes';
render(() => <Routes />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

UPD -> Upon further investigation, i found this issue is not with router but with solidjs library itself

Comment: Add `minify: false` to your `vite.config.ts` and try again - reading minified code is annoying. Also does the issue replicate after a `vite build` and `vite preview` command? I.e. does it only work in dev? I might try upgrading to the latest router and solid too.

Comment: FYI on StackOverflow you can answer your own question - may be worth giving details on what you mean by "but with solidjs library itself" - i.e. link a Github issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I have not upgraded any version of solidjs(1.3.12) nor solid-app-router(0.3.3). It has been deployed successfully 1 months ago, and now the build crashed, I am guessing the NPM entry may have been changed

Comment: can you check, you might have ^1.3.12 in your package.json which is upgrading to latest and latest versions have this issue. So your new build is using this and it is failing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have downgraded the version to `1.4.8` and it was working fine now in webview.
This error is not related to routes, rather it was of solidjs as i tried different versions, i was getting different errors in webview
1.6.14 -> `ws.not a function` , 1.5 -> `No is not a function`.

In 1.4.8 it was working fine in webview also

Also the issue was, i am using solid-app-router which is deprecated now and that version had this isseu which was fixed in later version when it was moved to @solidjs/router

Answer (score 0):

Update @solidjs/router to the lates, it works fine.

My current setup:
"solid-js": "^1.7.3",
"@solidjs/router": "^0.8.2",